# how to parse url query string into nodejs sql client

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I was wondering if anyone can help with parsing a query string with multiple types like this
`/api/v1/users?isFree=true&numberOfDays=23&name=Alice` to this query
`select * from users where isFree = true, numberOfDays = 23, name = "Alice"`. I tried this function using the mysql2 library:

```
async function findUsers(query) { // query would be parsed by expressjs as {isFree: 'true', numberOfDays: '23', name: 'Alice'}
  let queryString = "";
  let values = [];
  if (query != null) {
    const parsed = parseData(query);
    values = parsed.values;
    queryString = " where " + parsed.string.join(", ");
  }
  const out = await pool.query(queryString, values);
  queryString = "select * from users" + queryString; // queryString passed is " where isFree = ? "
  return (await pool.query(queryString, ["true"]))[0];
}
```

My main concern is that items that can be parsed as booleans and as numbers are left as strings. Should I build out my own logic like this?

```
function convertBooleans(options) {
  for (let key in options) {
    if (options[key] === "true") {
      options[key] = true;
    } else if (options[key] === "false") {
      options[key] = false;
    }
  }
  return options;
}
```

I feel icky about going this route. I tried using knex but that hasn't solved this issue of mixed types all being passed as a string. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try something like this -

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
var isFree= query.isFree;
var numberOfDays= query.numberOfDays;
var name= query.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you query you should validate or cast inputs, like

`req.query.isFree = !!req.query.isFree`

Then you could do (always use prepared querys, dont trust user input) to build the prepared query:

```
let keys = Object.keys(query)
let values = Object.values(query)

keys = keys.filter(v => ['isFree', 'numberOfDays', 'name'].includes(v))

let sql = 'SELECT * FROM vendors'
if (keys.length) sql += ` WHERE \`` + keys.join('` = ? AND `') + `\` = ?`

let result = await this.query(sql, values)
```

If your looking for something easier/lighter than knex, have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/autorm (I'm the only contributor ;p), then it would be as easy as:

```
let vendors = await database.findOne(
 'vendors', 
 'isFree = ? AND numberOfDays = ? AND name = ?', [
   !!req.query.isFree, 
   parseInt(req.query.numberOfDays, 10), 
   req.query.name || ''
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
https://github.com/alinoaimi/querytranslate
(I created it while I was working on an API that involved a lot of filtration)

You can use it to either convert the query to an SQL statement, or to a knex object.

```
let translatedQuery = QueryTranslate.translate({
    format: 'sql',
    query: 'filter[age][gt]=18&filter[language][in]=english&filter[language][in]=arabic&sort[]=points,desc&sort[]=id,desc&columns=id,name,country,language,points',
    tableName: 'users'
});
```

will be translated to:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`country`,`language`,`points` FROM `users` WHERE age > 18 AND language IN (`english`,`arabic`) ORDER BY points DESC, id DESC
```